# OAuth Facebook page as mobile (useragent and cordova)

Tags: facebook, cordova, oauth, agent

I had to change the User Agent in my cordova app so the google login continues to work (google seems to be blocking now the webviews to access their oauth workflow).

I added in the config.xml this preference:

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 Google" />
```

This fixed the google issues, but now the facebook login page does not load like a mobile device. It loads the browser login page (makes sense).

I found I way to force desktop mode:
http://www.facebook.com/?m2w

Is there something similar but to force the mobile version.

Should I use other user agent "Mozilla/5.0 Google"?

This URL needs to be in the mobile version: https://touch.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but since I had the same issue and got a solution, I'll post it:

**The direct copy-paste answer is:**

```
<preference name= "OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; One Build/KTU84L.H4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/28.0.0.20.16;] Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; One Build/KTU84L.H4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.135 Mobile Safari/537.36" />
```

And for other applications:

**Facebook for Android User-Agent string:**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; One Build/KTU84L.H4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/28.0.0.20.16;]
```

**Twitter for Android User-Agent string**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; One Build/KTU84L.H4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

**Chrome for Android User-Agent string**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; One Build/KTU84L.H4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.135 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

**Facebook for iOS User-Agent string**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12D508 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/27.0.0.10.12;FBBV/8291884;FBDV/iPhone7,1;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iPhone OS;FBSV/8.2;FBSS/3; FBCR/vodafoneIE;FBID/phone;FBLC/en_US;FBOP/5]
```

**Twitter for iOS User-Agent string**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12D508
```

Source: https://mobiforge.com/research-analysis/webviews-and-user-agent-strings

Answer (score 0):

Although you should not be overriding the useragent as you will have trouble with admob and you will get wrong analytics data. But since the webview with firebase auth is not working even with their give cordova oauth solution, Try using this instead:

`<preference name= "OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36" />`